# SyntaxError: missing : after property id - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the collection below:

```
    db.emp.insertMany(
    [
    {"name":"Nandhi","dept":"BPO","Salary":50000},
    {"name":"Raj","dept":"IT","Salary":5000},
    {"name":"Dave","dept":"IT","Salary":50000},
    {"name":"Pand","dept":"IT","Salary":50000},
    ]
    )
```

The requirement is to find the number of employees at each department whose salary is exactly 50000.

```
    db.emp.aggregate([
    {$match:{"Salary":50000}},
    {$group:{_id:{dept:"$dept"},cnt:{$sum,1}}}
    ])
```

Its throwing the error message: **missing : after property id.** But i am not seeing any issue with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma after `$sum` while MongoDB expects a colon there, try:

```
db.emp.aggregate([
    {$match:{"Salary":50000}},
    {$group:{_id:{dept:"$dept"},cnt:{$sum:1}}}
])
```